# Is there an equivalent for docker testing something like tox for Python?

Tags: docker, continuous-integration

`tox` allows you to test your code against different versions of Python. Is there something out there similar to `tox` that allows me to test my deployment code against different version of a distribution say like centos 7, 6.8, 6.5 etc ?

Comment: Is your code already being built in docker with a Dockerfile?

Comment: Currently in my C.I environment I pull down the docker image from docker hub.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases you would use some kind of Continuous Integration (CI) service, mostly coupled with some kind of version control system (VCS).

An example would be GitLab with GitLab CI or Gogs with drone.io. They use Docker containers to run your code and you can run your code in containers of different distributions.

Answer (score 0):

You could check [dox](https://github.com/openstack/dox). See this [blog article](https://blog.chmouel.com/2014/09/08/dox-a-tool-that-run-python-or-others-tests-in-a-docker-container/) for a short overview. In summary `dox` behaves like `tox` but instead of running virtualenvs you are using docker containers.

Comment: Thank you for the contribution? Could you try to incorporate the information on the links you mentioned into your answer? Links are volatile and could become dead anytime.

Comment: Sadly dox is a dead end.